# How to get rid of the "Grant File Access" dialog in Word 2016+AppleScript when inserting a picture

Tags: macos, applescript, ms-office

We use AppleScript to create MS Word documents, which also included pictures. This works fine with Word 2011, but I run into problems with Word 2016.

When opening files with Word 2016 via AppleScript, a "Grant File Access" dialog window pops up. This probably has to do with sandboxing. For opening documents I fixed it by passing a `file`-object to the `open` method:

```
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        open "path:to:some:file.docx" --Grant File Access dialog
        open file "path:to:some:file.docx" --No dialog, success!
```

However, when inserting a picture, I can't seem to find a way to pass a `file`-object. I use this code:

```
    set imageFile to choose file
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        open file someFilePath
        tell document someFileName
            make new inline picture at before text object of cell 1 of row 1 of table 1 ¬
              with properties {file name:(imageFile as text), save with document:true}
```

The property `file name` doesn't accept a `file`-object, and there is no property `file`.

Is there a way to get rid of this dialog?

Comment: I had slightly different problem: compare active document path "path:to:file.docx". To solve the problem I had to add "as POSIX file" at the end of the path: compare active document path "path:to:file.docx" as POSIX file